# Creating a local domain name for application server, on a box where port 80 is already in use

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, tomcat, internal-dns, coldfusion

I have a box running application server running on port 8500 and a web server on 80.  I am trying to create a local domain name for the application server on 8500.  I realize you cannot create a DNS record outside of port 80.  However, I already have a web server on 80. Is there a good solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

DNS A/CNAME records and ports are not related. Port 80 is just the default port for HTTP used by clients (e.g. browsers) and it's entirely possible to host one service at `http://example.org:80` and something else on `http://example.org:8500`.

If you don't want to use the port designation in the URL, you could configure your primary web server as reverse proxy that forwards `http://example.org/appserver` to `http://example.org:8500`, so both servers are seen as one acting on the same port (80) by the clients.

Answer (score 0):

The technology you are looking for is a [Reverse Proxy](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%22reverse%20proxy%22). We have lots of Q&A about it already.

Comment: I think this answer could be better if it explained why DNS is not what he's looking for, and why a reverse proxy would work.

Comment: If you think that then do it.